# Ocultar tabla o formulario en Javascript

Tags: javascript, html, bootstrap-4

Necesito ocultar un elemento de `HTLM` al utilizar la función `onclick()` de `Javascript`. Tengo un menú formado por un submenú de dos opciones, como el de la imagen:

[image: menu]

En la primera opción (Action) se muestra una tabla y en la segunda (another action) se muestra un formulario. Si hago click en Action y después en Another Action obtengo la tabla y debajo el formulario, no se oculta la tabla al mostrar el formulario.

El `HTLM` es el siguiente:

```
     <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="navbarNavDropdown">
        <ul class="navbar-nav">
        <li class="nav-item dropdown">
                <a class="nav-link dropdown-toggle" href="#" id="navbarDropdownMenuLink" data-toggle="dropdown" aria-haspopup="true" aria-expanded="false">
                  Dropdown link
                </a>
                <div class="dropdown-menu" aria-labelledby="navbarDropdownMenuLink">
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="origin()">Action</a>
                  <a class="dropdown-item" href="#" onclick="formOrigin()">Another action</a>
       </div>
       <div>
          <table class="table"></table>
       </div>
       <div>
          <form>
            <div class="form-group">
              <label for="name">Name</label>
              <input type="text" class="form-control" id="name" placeholder="Enter name">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group">
               <label for="city">City</label>
               <input type="text" class="form-control" id="city" placeholder="city">
            </div>
            <div class="form-group form-check">
               <input type="checkbox" class="form-check-input" id="add">
               <label class="form-check-label" for="add">Check</label>
            </div>
             <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
          </form>

       </div>
```

El código `Javascript` es:

```
    function origin() {

        var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/origin";
        petition.onreadystatechange = ResponseOrigin;
        petition.open("GET", url, true);
        petition.send();
        }

    function ResponseOrigin(){
        var response;
        text="<tr><th>Identifier</th><th>Name</th><th>Numero</th><th>City</th></tr>";
                if (petition.readyState == 4)
                    if (petition.status == 200) {
                        responser = petition.responseText;
                        var responseC = response.split("<");
                        var responseV = responseC[0];
                        var data = JSON.parse(responseV);
                        for (var i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {

                                text += "<tr id =" + data[i].id + "><td>" + data[i].id + "</td><td id='name'>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + 
                                data[i].city + "</td>";                                 

                        document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = text;

                        document.formOrigin.style.display="none";
                    }
                    else alert("Problem with URL");
            }

     function formOrigin() {


         var url = "http://localhost:8000/api/v1/origin";
            petition.onreadystatechange = responseAddOrigin;
            petition.open("POST", url, true);
            petition.send(JSON.stringify({name: document.formOrigin.name.value,
                city: document.formOrigin.city.value}));

       }
      function responseAddOrigen(){

            var response;
            if (petition.readyState == 4)
                if (petition.status == 200) {
                    response = petition.responseText;
                    alert ("data recorded correctly");
                }
                else
                    alert("Problem with URL");
        }
```

Alguna idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

La tienes liada en el bucle dentro del método responseOrigin(), no cierras el bucle donde se debe, estás todo el rato ejecutando dentro del bucle:

```
   document.getElementById('table').innerHTML = text;

   document.formOrigin.style.display="none";
```

Al mismo tiempo, esto mismo hace que el `else` de un fallo ya que el cierre del `if` que hay en ese método no se cierra donde debe porque no cierras el bucle de un error.

Aparte, de donde sacas el elemento DOM formOrigin? Es el nombre de una función pero no un elemento DOM, te sugiero que pruebes a ponerle una clase al div que contiene el formulario, y hacerle el `display="none"` a ese div.También, dentro de esa función `formOrigin()` asignas al `onreadystatechange` el valor que supongo se refiere `responseAddOrigen()` pero pone `responseAddOirigin`.

No obstante, arreglando esos errores, el código que muestras solo actualiza el contenido del elemento `<table>` y ocultas el formulario, pero no haces lo opuesto. Y en ningún sitio defines la variable petition, supongo que todas las variables a las que le falta una definición estarán en el código solo que no lo muestras, te aconsejo que muestres siempre todo lo que se relacione con el problema.

Aún así espero que estas indicaciones hayan servido, si es así, un voto siempre es bienvenido ;)

Answer (score 0):

Un problema inicial, se te ha pasado cerrar el string que crea los td:

```
text += "<tr id =" + data[i].id + "><td>" + data[i].id + "</td><td id='name'>" + data[i].name + "</td><td>" + 
 data[i].city + "</td> -->";<--
```